# Issue installing mongodb-community@5.0

Tags: mongodb

I'm tryimg to install mongodb-community throgh brew, however, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: undefined method name' for nil:NilClass Please report this issue: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:275:in block in initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:274:in map' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:274:in initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:561:in new' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:561:in loader_for'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:420:in factory' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cli/parser.rb:633:in block in formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cli/parser.rb:629:in map' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cli/parser.rb:629:in formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cli/parser.rb:308:in parse' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:141:in install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:110:in
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I'm trying to install it through the Mac's Terminal using the following code:  brew install mongodb-community@5.0

Comment: Check this one: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/